# Multiple Dynamic OptionMenu using DataFrame in Python Tkinter GUI-PY_VAR21 Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have been working on filtering the DataFrame rows so that I could arrive at a Single row with respect to different options chosen in OptionMenus in sequence.
I did try to store the selected variable from OptionMenu and when I printed it, I get

'PY_VAR21'

as output.

Can you kindly clarify me. I enclose my datafile where I am willing to have Multiple dynamic OptionMenus where selected value goes further to another class.

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):

        self.zero=data.Category.unique()     
        self.variable0=StringVar()        
        option_menu=OptionMenu(master,self.variable0,*self.zero)        
        option_menu.pack()        

x=MyClass()
aa=x.variable0
print aa
mainloop()
```

I have got thousands of values and categories in each column and thus I want to automate the Dynamic OptionMenu using the available DataFrame.

I have been trying with different approaches and am failing for many number of days.Thank you.[Datafile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re2Ff.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see the `PY_VAR21` that is the instance of the variable. However if you say:

```
print self.variable0.get()
```

you should see the actual value of the variable.

Comment: Dear Luke, I did try with adding .get(). But it does not display anything now . Please note that I tried to print variable outside function. Thank you for your efforts in helping me.

Comment: @Mari: if it "does not display anything now" that probably just means that the variable is set to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

see below for printing the variable outside the class after the loop has finished.

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI():


    def __init__(self, master):
        self.variable0 = StringVar()
        self.variable0.set('Option1')
        self.option = OptionMenu(master, self.variable0, 'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3')
        self.option.pack()

        self.close = Button(master, text='Close', command=master.quit)
        self.close.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root = Tk()
x = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()

var = x.variable0
print var.get()
```

Comment: Dear @Luke Thank you for your efforts in helping me. Kindly note that I wish to display multiple Optionmenus where 'variable0' will go as an Input to filter the Dataframe and then list out the     .unique() values. I wish to use that variable within my window (root). but may be outside the class GUI.

Comment: root = Tk()
x = GUI(root)
var = x.variable0
print var.get()
root.mainloop()   When I tried this (Inserting the print statement within root window, I just get the option which is set as Option 1 as default. This does not print the selected option but the 'set' option. Thank you.

Comment: printing the variable within the loop will always show the default value though.... thats how the loop works. Unless you have a seperate function to print the variable after you have selected an option.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Luke, Bryan. I got to understand and solve it. Thanks for your help. They helped on time.

Comment: Happy to help. Glad you got it sorted!